# Django KeyError at /name/ in Django Form

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get name and surname values and print it to HTML. This is my code:

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from emailai.models import Vartotojas
from renginiai.forms import VartotojasForm

def name(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = VartotojasForm(request.GET)
        name = form.data['name']
        surname = form.data['surname']
        return render(request, 'vartotojas-result.html', {'form': form, 'name': names, 'surname': surname })
    else:
        form = VartotojasForm()
        return render(request, 'vartotojas-form.html', {'form': form})
```

Vartotojas-form.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Name</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Name</h1>
    <form action="sumbit" method="get">
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

I am getting KeyError at /name/ . Where is my mistake?

Comment: Can you show the form that's submitting this? Presumably there's no "name" in your form data.

Comment: Why you use `GET` method instead of `POST` in your `Vartotojas-form.html` form?

Comment: OK I messed up a little. Now it fixed, but still it don't work properly.

Comment: I update my answer. also why you send again the `form` to this `'vartotojas-result.html'` template ?

Comment: How else to print the data from template?

Comment: Just send `name` and `surname` variables to this `vartotojas-result.html` template.

Comment: Thanks, finally it worked. Ahh... I still need to learn POST and GET theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VartotojasForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            surname = form.cleaned_data['surname']
            return render(request, 'vartotojas-result.html', {'form': form, 'name': name, 'surname': surname })
    else:
        form = VartotojasForm()
    return render(request, 'vartotojas-form.html', {'form': form})
```

Also in render parameters , your `names` variable is undefined:

```
{'form': form, 'name': names, 'surname': surname }
```

change it to `name`:

```
{'form': form, 'name': name, 'surname': surname }
```

And change your `Vartotojas-form.html` form to:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Name</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Name</h1>
    <form action="sumbit" method="post">
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. However, now it shows "•This field is required" on tp of the fields. Is is because cleaned_data ? And how to delete that?

Comment: Please paste content of `vartotojas-form.html` file in your question. That is `errors` of your form, because you define `name` and `surname` in `VartotojasForm` form as required fields.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your template uses name parameter in the input tag

```
<input type="text" name="surname" value="">
<input type="text" name="name" value="">
```

and that the fields in Django form match the fields in html form